# Task oriented robot language?

Tags: planning

So, what I understood by the term "[Task Planning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56373815/159072)" is, "to implement a task to be done by a robot by mimicking a real-world scenario".

[This article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957415899000471) is also using the term "Task" but it is saying something different.

> ... To enable user-friendly operation of the system operation, particularly in the phase of preparing new **tasks**, the original Multi-arm Robot Control (MRC) system has been developed. It incorporates a **task-oriented robot language** and graphical user interface ...

So, is this article talking about the same thing or different?

I am confused. Coz, their description is unclear.

Are they creating a new programming language and embedding it into the robot, or are they planning a task using an "off-the-shelf" programming language?

Comment: `coz` is not a word .... please correct your grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to motion planning, task planning operates on a symbolic higher level. Often, it's connected to natural language descriptions like “open door” and “stand-up”. This makes it a natural choice for a domain specific language. The words in the new language are equal to the actions a robot can execute.

The alternative would be, to realize the tasks in a normal programming language like C++. But then, the actions are also equal to high-level words which are defined in a class. In both cases the idea is to build on top of the low level primitives an elaborated natural language layer which makes it easier to author longer robotics action sequences. A single task command is equal to many low level actions of the robot.

If the tasks are embedded in a simulation the resulting symbolic task simulator is called qualitative physics engine. The model accepts instructions in natural language and predicts the outcome of the action.